# ember-data findAll not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the `ember-data` last version with an important problem I 'm trying to solve.

The `find` function by id works perfect and the proper record is loaded into the Data Store so I can obtain the attributes that I want in the template for render them.

```js
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
```

On the other side, the `findAll` function doesn't work for me and the problem is Ember doesn't throw any error. In addition, Ember doesn't load any record and besides that I don't know how to iterate over the `RecordArray` returned in the template.

```js
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your json response from your endpoint?

Comment: My JSON response for one post is `{"id":"1","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"}` while my JSON response for all posts is `[{"id":"1","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"},{"id":"2","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"}]`. I'm aware of my no ember standard response so I'm using `RESTSerializer`.

Comment: You'll need to give us the serializer in order to debug.  Additionally you can iterate over the response: this.store.find('post').then(function(arr){ console.log(arr.get('length'));});

Comment: My RESTSerializer is exactly like the `TRANSITION.md` one with 'serializerIntoHash`, `extractSingle` and `extractArray` functions but finally I gonna forget this serializer system and I gonna use a JSON response according to Ember so it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment above, if your response looks like:

```
[
    {"id":"1","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"},
    {"id":"2","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"}
]
```

and you have not provided a custom serializer that modifies your response in `extractArray(...)`, then data will not get processed because Ember Data expects something like:

```
{
    "pluralizedModelName": [
        {"id":"1","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"},
        {"id":"2","attribute1":"value1", ...,"attributen": "valuen"}
    ]
}
```

See the Ember Data 1.0 specific code: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#rest-adapter-and-serializer-configuration

Comment: The issue is I was using `extractSingle` and `extractArray` indeed but finally  I'd decided to change my JSON response for avoid those problems so it works now!

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the model in the template? Are you using the generated controller, or defining it yourself?

Also, the RecordArray should be automatically resolved by your Handlebars template. Try referencing {{#each}}. By default, your template will look for the property on the controller and if not found, bubble up to the model. If you can, create a JSBin (emberjs.jsbin.com) and we can collaborate with an example.

Edit: Also, are you using Fixture or Rest Adapter?

Comment: I'm using `RESTAdapter`, `RESTSerializer` and also the generated controller because I return my json data in the model route like above.

Comment: And I'd already tried With `{{#each}}` but my template doesn't render anything. The issue is that if I return `$.getJSON` instead it works partially. I mean, it renders my data but it doesn't load it into the data store.